# Android | Add Navigation Drawer to default Maps Activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, navigation-drawer

I've been searching for the answer to this for weeks now, so please excuse if I seem a little frustrated. It's because I am.

In advance, sorry if this question has been asked before. I'm new to Android programming (I mostly do web-apps) and this is a whole new world to me. All help is appreciated!

What I want to do is add a Navigation Drawer to a standard run of the mill maps activity. How would I go about doing this? I want each button to be able to recenter the map to another place as well.

While we're at it, I plan on creating a KML layer in my map. As you know, KML points have information built into them so that when you tap/click on them you can see the info. I want to have the KML point open the Navigation Drawer with its built-in-information. I'm fine using the default android points for this, but something with KML is appreciated. If you want a frame of reference, think something like this JavaScript example but with the sidebar hidden most of the time: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package us.tourismproject.jared.tourismprojectandroid;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    try {
        // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
        // in a raw resource file.
        boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.style_json));

        if (!success) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
    }
    // Position the map's camera near Sydney, Australia.
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(-34, 151)));
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="us.tourismproject.jared.tourismprojectandroid.MainActivity" />
```

Thanks for any help in advance. Good day now!

Comment: what do you want? You want to add navigation drawer in MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, you need to wrap your `Fragment` inside another parent layout which includes`Navigation drawer` and then set up things for `drawer` in java.
Refer [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Coming to interaction part, `KML` is just a notation, which holds some information, what you can do is create a `marker` for each KML geo points and tie it to a click function of `marker` to open `Navigation drawer`.

[Check here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker) for adding Markers to Google Maps

Comment: How would I go about creating the click function for all of the KML points? I have very limited knowledge of Java/Android. I got the map to work though, so kudos to you.

Comment: Figured it out! I used OnMarkerClickListener to create a boolean of onMarkerClick which checks which marker has been clicked. It then opens a seperate fragment. Thanks for all the help man!

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want navigation drawer over your map activity than update your **activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

        <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="us.tourismproject.jared.tourismprojectandroid.MainActivity" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- Draw your view whatever you want to draw -->

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

It will create your navigation drawer as one answer mention by rajan, you need to write some code for handling navigation drawer.